Unable to Build Expo in Vanilla React Native iOS Project Due to Unsupported Swift Version in Xcode 15.4
I'm trying to configure a bare React Native project with Expo for EAS. Here's what I've done so far:

Installed the Expo modules using npx install-expo-modules@latest.
Ran pod install.
Attempted to run the app in the iOS simulator using
react-native run-ios.

However, the build failed with the following error:
error Failed to build ios project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code '65'. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening 'AwesomeProject.xcworkspace'.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace AwesomeProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme AwesomeProject -destination id=00008130-000260943E8B803A

Following the suggestion, I opened the AwesomeProject.xcworkspace file in Xcode and encountered this message:
Unsupported Swift Version

The target “AwesomeProjectTests” contains
source code developed with Swift 3.x.
This version of Xcode does not support
building or migrating Swift 3.x targets.

Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4.

Interestingly, the Android build works fine, and running npx expo run:ios also builds everything successfully. I'm confused because I thought npx expo run:ios would also rely on the Xcode build process.
Additional Info:

Xcode version: 15.4 (15F31d)

Questions:

Why am I encountering the Swift version error with react-native run-ios, but not with npx expo run:ios?
How can I resolve the Swift version issue to successfully build my
project using react-native run-ios?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
